# How to change apache domain name(locally) for a laravel site on ubuntu?

Tags: php, laravel, apache

Good day guys in my application I want to change the normal `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` that laravel uses to serve sites when one runs `php artisan serve` to `example.com` and this should have sub domains like `app1.example.com` and `app2.example.com`.

In the main time I have tried to create a virtual host for my site by creating a **.conf** file inside of `etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com.conf` and here is how it looks:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>


    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /home/tangaye/sites/example/public/index.php

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

After doing that I enable the virtual host I created by running `sudo a2ensite example.com.conf` and `sudo service apache2 reload` to reload apache2 configuartions and `sudo service apachIe2 restart` from the on I added the address my site points to in `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost    example.com
127.0.1.1   tangaye
```

After doing all this when I run `php artisan serve` from my laravel site directory I still see my site being launch like this:

> Laravel development server started: http://127.0.0.1:8000

After all I have done I expected to rather see this:

> Laravel development server started: example.com

The worst thing is when I try to access example.com in my browser it tends to search for it on the internet.

At this point I don't really understand what really I'm doing. All I want is to be able to customize my site domain name **LOCALLY** and add other sub domains.
Will appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can't specify port numbers in `/etc/hosts`. There's no way to get around that part.

You should be able to just throw `example.com` after the `localhost` definition:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost example.com
```

and then it will also resolve to 127.0.0.1 ... then it's just a matter of name-based hosting configurations in Apache. Your file looks pretty good, but `DocumentRoot` is specifying a folder, not a file. Remember to do an `a2ensite` to enable your site (it's really just creating a symlink in `sites-enabled` pointing at the `sites-available` file) and restart Apache.

To avoid your browser interpreting a web address as a search term, you can prefix it with `http://`

Comment: do have an idea on how I do name-based hosting configurations in Apache? Also I did made the changes you suggested, but still no luck.

Comment: The files in `sites-available` control Apache's name-based hosting. The rule sets use the value in `ServerName`. 

Verify name-resolution with `ping example.com` ... it should hit 127.0.0.1. 
Look in sites-enabled to confirm symlink exists. 

That's about all there is to it.

Comment: I'm getting: ping: unknown host example.com

Comment: Then it is not added to `/etc/hosts` properly. Double-check that. That file is consulted before your computer attempts name resolution with DNS.

Comment: Oh crazy me I added `http://` before example.com in `/etc/hosts` It is now pinging on 127.0.0.1

Comment: If it's pinging now, and it works with http://localhost:8080, you should definitely be able to go to http://example.com:8080

Answer (score 1):

Note that PHP's built-in development server and Apache are two completely separate ways to serve a PHP webpage/app.

`php artisan serve` is a rapid development tool, allowing for easy access to a PHP project without the need to set up a full-fledged web server (e.g. Apache). All you need is PHP and you can run Laravel or other PHP projects. (It's also important to note that this should be used for development **only**, never in production.)

Apache, on the other hand, is a full-featured web server, with all the bells and whistles, including virtual host management. And it works over port 80, so no need to add the port to your URLs.

If you want to use a named URL in your development environment, you should:

1. Install Apache
2. Configure Apache, including virtual hosts and PHP configuration.
3. Modify your hosts file to point your chosen development domain name to your local machine (or the machine serving your app, which could be a Vagrant box, Docker, etc. if you choose to use such tools).
4. Don't bother using `php artisan serve` at all.

Comment: I've apache install. As of the configurations I don't know how well I've configure it. I think apache is working fine because when I copy my project folder into `/var/ww/` and type `localhost` in my browser I see it trying to launch my project it's just that I'm encountering few errors.

Comment: You should include any errors you're getting in your post. Most of the steps you outlined in your post seem correct. What happens when you go to `example.com`?

Comment: I have finally resolve all errors. Now the problem I now have is the only way I can view my site is by typing `localhost` in the browser. `example.com` gives me nothing, but when I ping it I see it on `127.0.0.1`